# How to create a virtual audio cable using Python

Tags: python-3.x, audio

So, we have [VB-Audio](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/), which will create Virtual Audio Cable in your system. I want to do something similiar, but I couldn't find anything on the internet.
So, I am wondering, **is there a way to do this in Python 3?** I don't think this will be entirely Python, as I suggest that this may require usage of C via external libraries. *Either way, the important part is, it has to be working on Python 3+.*

**NOTE: I need for the solution to be for Windows 10.**

Comment: Great ! What have you tried ?

Comment: @TGrif Nothing, I couldn't find anything. I have no clue how to do this.

Comment: Search for virtual microphone. It's not OS-agnostic, on linux you can use e.g. `pulsectl`. You will easily find articles explaining how to change source and sink

Comment: @LukaszTracewski Doesn't help, I am still finding nothing. Also, I should've said that I am doing this for Windows, not for Linux.

Comment: Please note that "Virtual Audio Cable" is the name of the software product not related to VB-Audio (their software that you use, is called VB-Cable). Please don't confuse them.

Creation of the audio endpoints requires some advanced techniques that are not available in Python. For example, VAC and VB-Cable are kernel-mode Kernel Streaming drivers, exposing the appropriate features to Windows processes and services. Kernel-mode drivers cannot be written in Python.

Answer (score 0):

try to do with jack

```
import jack

print("setting error/info functions")


@jack.set_error_function
def error(msg):
    print("Error:", msg)


@jack.set_info_function
def info(msg):
    print("Info:", msg)


print("starting chatty client")

client = jack.Client("Chatty-Client")

if client.status.server_started:
    print("JACK server was started")
else:
    print("JACK server was already running")
if client.status.name_not_unique:
    print("unique client name generated:", client.name)


print("registering callbacks")


@client.set_shutdown_callback
def shutdown(status, reason):
    print("JACK shutdown!")
    print("status:", status)
    print("reason:", reason)


@client.set_freewheel_callback
def freewheel(starting):
    print(["stopping", "starting"][starting], "freewheel mode")


@client.set_blocksize_callback
def blocksize(blocksize):
    print("setting blocksize to", blocksize)


@client.set_samplerate_callback
def samplerate(samplerate):
    print("setting samplerate to", samplerate)


@client.set_client_registration_callback
def client_registration(name, register):
    print("client", repr(name), ["unregistered", "registered"][register])


@client.set_port_registration_callback
def port_registration(port, register):
    print(repr(port), ["unregistered", "registered"][register])


@client.set_port_connect_callback
def port_connect(a, b, connect):
    print(["disconnected", "connected"][connect], a, "and", b)


try:
    @client.set_port_rename_callback
    def port_rename(port, old, new):
        print("renamed", port, "from", repr(old), "to", repr(new))
except AttributeError:
    print("Could not register port rename callback (not available on JACK1).")


@client.set_graph_order_callback
def graph_order():
    print("graph order changed")


@client.set_xrun_callback
def xrun(delay):
    print("xrun; delay", delay, "microseconds")


print("activating JACK")
with client:
    print("#" * 80)
    print("press Return to quit")
    print("#" * 80)
    input()
    print("closing JACK")
```